# How do I pass the data in a loop to an onclick (React.js)

Tags: reactjs

I will put in the code first.

```
{gameModes.map((gameMode, key) => {
            return (
              <>
                <div className={styles.gameMode} key={key} onClick={gameModeHandler}>
                  <div className={styles.gameModeContent}>
                    <img src={gameMode.gameModeArtwork} alt="" />
                    <p className={styles.modeTitle}>{gameMode.gameModeTitle}</p>
                    <p className={styles.modeDesc}>
                      {gameMode.gameModeDesc}
                    </p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </>
            );
          })}
```

**The onClick function**

```
const gameModeHandler = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.value)
  }
```

Basically what I want is, when the onClick takes effect it passes in the gameMode.title to the onClick to console.log it. I do not know how to pass the onClick in a way where it has access to that data in the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to use a callback function for your onClick event. And adjust your function thus;

**The onClick event**

```
onClick={()=>gameModeHandler(gameMode.gameModeTitle)}
```

**The onClick function**

```
 const gameModeHandler = (gameModeTitle) => {
    console.log(gameModeTitle)
  }
```

However, if you wish to pass a single object from your loop to the invoked function, you may just pass the **gameMode** object as an argument to the gameModeHandler function thus;

**The onClick event**

```
onClick={()=>gameModeHandler(gameMode)}
```

**The onClick function**

```
 const gameModeHandler = (gameMode) => {
    console.log(gameMode)
  }
```

Apparently, you can subsequently extract the ***gameModeTitle*** from the object thus;

```
console.log(gameMode.gameModeTitle)
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a second function to pass the data: `onClick={() => gameModeHandler(gameMode.title)}`.

Comment: I am getting undefined. Am i displaying it the right way in the gameModeHandler ?

Comment: Is it `gameMode.title` or `gameMode.gameModeTitle`? Looks like you have one in the code and the other in your question.

Comment: I fixed it now that you mentioned the gameMode.gameModeTitle. I just changed the gameMode.title part and instead of the console.log(e.target.event) I console only e

Comment: Ah yeah, since you're calling the function with the title, you won't have an event/event target.